# view group instance

Tags: android, viewgroup

I am very new to android... Can anyone let me know how I can get a handle on the viewgroup?

For example:

I have a linear layout in my `main.xml` file. 
The only way I have been able to add views are by 
using `findViewById` and specifying the id of the linear layout. I want to develop a generic method which gets a handle on the viewgroup and performs functions like `getChildCount()` 
etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own layout subclass and override some methods such as `onFinishInflate()`. The [View documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) has some information about that and you'll find lots of tutorials about how to do it.

This is what I explain in [one of my tutorials](http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/custom-listview-ability-check-items/) to get all the Checkable views of a layout.

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    final int childCount = this.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
        findCheckableChildren(this.getChildAt(i));
    }
}

/**
 * Add to our checkable list all the children of the view that implement the
 * interface Checkable
 */
private void findCheckableChildren(View v) {
    if (v instanceof Checkable) {
        this.checkableViews.add((Checkable) v);
    }

    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
        final int childCount = vg.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
            findCheckableChildren(vg.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. but i am writing a generic class which gets all the EditText fields and posts it to a restful resource. So i need to develop a generic code that i can use in other applications.Hence i do not want to use a findViewById method in which case is specific to that application..